# How to include the current user's path on a file?

Tags: c#, connection

I have a file in a folder on a user's local drive. I want to reference it by just the last few folders, how do i do that? example:

```
string filePath = \\folder\file.txt;
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140383/how-can-i-get-the-current-user-directory

Comment: How would you use what? Have you read the link i've posted? Does it answer your question? No, why?

Comment: string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)/folder/file.txt; ?

Comment: Use the `System.IO.Path` class, especially `Combine`: `string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "/folder/file.txt‌");`

Comment: (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) = what in the file path? Like does it equal C:/Users/CurrentUser ?

Answer (score 0):

Use "GetParent"

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); //current path
string path1 = Directory.GetParent(path).ToString(); //parent of current path
string path2 = Directory.GetParent(path1).ToString(); //parent..
string path3 = Directory.GetParent(path2).ToString(); //parent..
```

Optimize it if you really want to use it. It just shows how it works.