# Pythonnet Import Error Visbrain in Anaconda 3

Tags: c#, importerror, python.net

Environment :

- Pythonnet version: 2.3.0, installed with pip in Amaconda3
- Python version: 3.6.6 using with Anaconda
- Visual Studio 2017 Community
- Operating System: Windows 7, 64 bit

I am running Visbrain module by Pythonnet.
I had create a virtual environment named py36 in Anaconda 3. Anaconda 3 is in D drive.
Trying to run below code in my c# program.

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
 dynamic np = Py.Import("visbrain");
}
```

But it pops out an error which is

```
Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'visbrain''
```

stack trace :

```
Python.Runtime.PythonException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'visbrain'
  Source=Python.Runtime
  StackTrace:
```

i had visbrain under Lib\site-packages.

Tried Solution but did not success:

1) add PATH, PYTHONHOME in environment variable.
PATH : D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36;
PYTHONHOME : D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36;

2) [pythonnet Embedding Python in .net example failing to load module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559658/pythonnet-embedding-python-in-net-example-failing-to-load-module)
added PYTHONPATH : D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Lib\site-packages;

===

i am strange that "numpy" module is also inside of the Lib\site-packages.

when i tried below example

```
dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
```

It is fine.

Would like to know what is the issue here and how to solve this, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

according to https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows,-Linux,-and-OSX

it mentioned

> "Unable to load DLL pythonXX": CPython is not installed, or not
>   registered in %PATH% and %PYTHONHOME% environment variables.
>   Alternatively set PythonEngine.PythonHome property before initializing
>   Python runtime.

Instead of setting up PythonHome and Path manually, you set them up by coding.

before `PythonEngine.Initialize();`
just remember to set the PATH and PYTHONHOME, just as example

```
// Modify Path
string path = @"d:\Anaconda3\envs\py36;" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine); 

// Set Path
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

// Set PythonHome
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", @"d:\Anaconda3\envs\py36", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

// Set PythonPath
// ONLY SET THIS IF YOU ARE SURE WHAT YOU ARE DOING
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", @"d:\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Lib", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Miniconda, apparently Python.NET does not work well with conda. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63605963/8298327): best is do reinstall python (without conda).