# C#: How to make a string with a path of the Current User's directory?

Tags: c#

So basically I need a string "path" to be something like:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\file.txt";
```

How could I do that?

Sincerely,

a guy with an internet connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current user directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140383/how-can-i-get-the-current-user-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your User profile path stores in

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
```

To get specifc file path from that Folder you need to combine it with hard coded string of your file name, like

```
 string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "file.txt")
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Do not forget to add `using System.IO` because `Path` class is present in `System.IO`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` enumeration.

```
string path=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```